# Dojo StackController: how can I set a title for each button?

Tags: html, dojo

(using [dojo 1.10.1](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.1/dojo/dojo.js))

I am working with dojo's [dijit/layout/StackContainer and dijit/layout/StackController](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/layout/StackContainer.html) which are working fine, here is a [simplified example](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremybrooks321/5jd4h8o0/). My problem is that I cant find a "clean" way to add mouseover titles to each controller button that the StackController creates?

html

```
<div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/StackContainer"
             data-dojo-props="id: 'contentStack'">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="one">
                <h4>Group 1 Content</h4>
            </div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="two">
                <h4>Group 2 Content</h4>
            </div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="three">
                <h4>Group 3 Content</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/StackController" data-dojo-props="containerId:'contentStack'"></div>
    </div>
```

So for each title in each child contained within the StackContainer, a button is cerated by the StackController with the same label, but the button has no mouseover text, I need to add that as well.

I am not interested in any solution that involves me looping over the nodes and finding each button, its just not nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best solutions would be to send properties, methods and events of buttons via corresponding ContentPanes. For example:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="one" data-dojo-props=
"controllerProps: {onMouseOver: function(){"doSomething"}}">
    <h4>Group 1 Content</h4>
</div>
```

But as far as I understood this is not possible, because StackController passes to its buttons "title" and some other unimportant properties of ContentPane. So if you are really interested in above solutions you have to override the default behavior of StackController. Which is possible, but needs more time! :)

So I suggest you other solution which works and faster. You give to StackController-div an id:

```
<div id="myController" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/StackController" data-dojo-
props="containerId:'contentStack'"></div>
```

You use "dijit/registry" to call that id:

```
var controllerWidget = registry.byId("myController");
```

You have now StackController widget. Call *getChildren()* method of it and you have an array of Button widgets. The rest I guess straightforward.

Here is the [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/atoha/4vydnd9a/).

Cheers!

**Update:**

Hey I have found another solution, which satisfies your requirements: "No button search"

These are the properties which StackController passes to buttonWidget:

```
var Cls = lang.isString(this.buttonWidget) ? lang.getObject(this.buttonWidget) : this.buttonWidget;
var button = new Cls({
    id: this.id + "_" + page.id,
    name: this.id + "_" + page.id, // note: must match id used in pane2button()
    label: page.title,
    disabled: page.disabled,
    ownerDocument: this.ownerDocument,
    dir: page.dir,
    lang: page.lang,
    textDir: page.textDir || this.textDir,
    showLabel: page.showTitle,
    iconClass: page.iconClass,
    closeButton: page.closable,
    title: page.tooltip,
    page: page
});
```

So if you give a tag "tooltip" for your ContentPane, it will appear in buttonWidget as "title".

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="one" tooltip="First Page">
```

Here is another [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/atoha/51mfkqzm/).